# Why is the inclusive range operator throwing an error when the exclusive operator does not?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use a `ForEach` to build the options of a picker in SwiftUI, but the range operator doesn't seem to be working as I would expect it to.

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var inputString = ""
@State private var inputUnits = 0

let units = ["Fahrenheit", "Celsius", "Kelvin"]

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Convert:")) {
            TextField("Enter input", text: $inputString)
            Picker("Unit", selection: $inputUnits) {
                ForEach(0 ... 2) {
                    Text("\(self.units[$0])")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The compiler has an issue with the `...` range operator. It throws two errors:

1. Generic parameter 'ID' could not be inferred
2. Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'Int' conform to 'Identifiable'

The curious thing here is that the `..<` operator works fine here, so if I use this line of code instead, the code compiles:

```
ForEach(0 ..< 3) {
```

This seems like a bug to me, but is there some difference between these operators that I am not aware of?

Comment: I believe you should go for "For" loop with Range operators instead of "ForEach". Also remove space, "0...2" or "0..<3"

Comment: Agreed totally obnoxious - not at all obvious why it's erroring (Xcode 11.3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference:

For `Range<Int>` (`..<`) operator there is explicit extension of `ForEach` which specifies associated types

> ```
> @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> extension ForEach where Data == Range<Int>, ID == Int, Content : View {
> ```

whereas for `ClosedRange<Int>` (`...`) there is no such, and it is considered as collection by more generic

> ```
> /// A structure that computes views on demand from an underlying collection of
> /// of identified data.
> @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> public struct ForEach<Data, ID, Content> where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable {
> ```

so requires explicit providing of ID type as below

```
ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) {
```

or you can declare your own extension

```
extension ForEach where Data == ClosedRange<Int>, ID == Int, Content : View {
    public init(_ data: ClosedRange<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        self.init(data, id: \.self, content: content)
    }
}
```

and then just use

```
ForEach(0...2) {
```

Comment: Super interesting. Thanks! Do you think there is a reason it was implemented this way? It seems counter-intuitive to me to have these operators behave differently.

Comment: It is kind of convenience for most of us used to work with `for` as `0..<N`, however ... of course, I can't read in Apple's engineer mind. ))

Answer (score 3):

This is because `0 ... 2` is a `ClosedRange<Int>` and `0 ..< 3` is a `Range<Int>`.

If you look at the `init` functions of `ForEach` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach) you will see that there is this: `init(Range<Int>, content: (Int) -> Content)` which matches the use of your `0 ..< 3`.

In many other places in swift you can mix `...` and `..<` because the function is either overloaded or it has a `Collection` can use generics with the `RangeExpression` protocol. In this case since `ForEach` doesn't have a `Collection` backing it other than your input so an overload is the only reasonable option.

This can be accomplished like this:

```swift
extension ForEach where Data == ClosedRange<Int>, ID == Int, Content: View {
    public init(_ data: ClosedRange<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        self.init(data, id: \.self, content: content)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution to implement ForEach with Range operators is as follows:-

For Array of count 3

First with Closed Range is

```
    ForEach(0...2, id: \.self){ index in
            Text("\(self.array[index])")
        }
```

Second is

```
    ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self){ index in
            Text("\(self.array[index])")
        }
```